# Group By processed row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using a `sqlite` db where I don't have a real `DateTime` type support. So I just store millisecondssinceepoch as int. My records look like this:

```
id, value, date

0, 20, 1624135478030
1, 24, 1624278137460
2, 234, 1624134777839
...
```

Now I'd like to group my records by the `day` (not date) and get the biggest sum of `value` from all record from the same day. Is there a way where I can do this inline in my SQL statement?

If `date` would just be the 'day', my query would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(value) as sumValue FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY date ORDER BY sumValue DESC
```

But I need to somehow extract the day from my milliseconds-date and group by that. Is this possible?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to convert it:

```
SELECT DATE(DATETIME(date / 1000, 'unixepoch'), SUM(value) as sumValue
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY DATE(DATETIME(date / 1000, 'unixepoch')
ORDER BY sumValue DESC;
```

Note:  If you are content with the "unix" timestamp as a date, you can use arithmetic:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60) as INT), 
       SUM(value) as sumValue
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY CAST(DATE / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60) as INT)
ORDER BY sumValue DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for this great fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `date()` directly with your unixepoch dates to extract the date part only:

```
SELECT date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS day, 
       SUM(value) AS sumValue
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY sumValue DESC;
```